# MySQL String conversion to Expression

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

I have a MySQL Routine having condition:

```
Where category like CONCAT("%",@category,"%")
```

...and this works fine with single category.

Now I want to compare with multiple categories, I tried with building string from PHP (string concatenation) but its not working (in Mysql Routine).

How can I convert this condition to match multiple LIKE Expression ?

Comment: Please paste what your tried for string concatenation

Comment: You'll have to explain how you are storing the `category` value -- looks like you're putting numerous category words into a single column (what we call "Denormalized Data" -- not good.)

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337817#337817 ?

Comment: I changed condition in routine like "Where @category" and passed 'category like "%cat1%" or category like "%cat2%"'. But its not working ... I guess MySQL routine is taking parameter as string like 'Where {String}' ...

Comment: How can I pass multiple category values to @category ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your category column is like: "cats, dogs, elephants"; separated keywords. there are 3 solutions :

**1)** Ugliest solution, probably the worst :

```
WHERE category like CONCAT("%",@category1,"%") 
OR category like CONCAT("%",@category2,"%")
```

But for this you should know how many categories you are gonna query for. This way probably wont work at all.

**2)** If its a myisam table you can use [full-text search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) to match against category field which would be much more faster and tidier than 1st option.

**3)** The best way is to redesign table structure to have a relation table between categories and subject item (since it seems like a 1-N relationship)

If you can give some definitions (codes) and data samples that would help understanding.